# Adobe air transparent Windows system tray icon appears as a black block

Tags: javascript, air, adobe

In Windows, my Adobe air application needs a 100% transparent tray icon. But it always appears as a black block. I tried loading a 100% transparent image and creating a 100% transparent `BitmapData`, but no one works.

create a 100% transparent `BitmapData`:

```
var transparentImage = new air.BitmapData(16, 16, true, 0);
```

and set the tray icon image as this new image.

```
air.NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon.bitmaps = [transparentImage];
```

In fact, I loaded another image which is not 100% transparent, it appears normally.

So what I missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just now I edited my PNG image to make my application works well.

At first the image is 100% transparent, I opened it with photoshop and fill it with a color with 90% transparent.

Then the system tray icon appears normally.